# height and width property are not applying to html img element

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am building a full stack,server-side rendered react e commerce app. However since css is my weak point I tried to build product card instead of using library templates. however the issue is I could not figure out how to make `img` element cover the div. when I place `height` and `width` properties `img` disappears. it might be an easy question for many of you but i could not figure out :(

here is the react component code:

```
<div className="card-body ">
          <div className="card-img-container">
            <img src={imageUrl} alt={name} className="card-img" />
          </div>


<div className="card-footer">
          <span className="name">{name}</span>
          <span>
            <div className="price-and-dollar">
              <span className="dollar-sign">$</span>
              <span className="price"> {price}</span>
            </div>
          </span>
        </div>
</div>
```

here is the css:

```
.collection-item {
  background-color: $gray-700;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 23vw;
  .card-body {
    width: 94%;
  }
}
.card-img-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.card-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

here is the result

[image]

Comment: Do you want this cart icon to cover the whole card? or the upper part? till its most right?

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
.card-img-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div.card-img-container > img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: it is still same :(

Answer (score 0):

```
.card-img-container {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
.card-img {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Try this hope it will be helpful

Comment: You have to check dependency. I think you next css will overwrite current one